# roblox lua script not activating

Tags: scripting, lua, roblox

so i have this code

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local unitFrame = script.Parent
local buttona = unitFrame.buttonA
local sprinting = true

unitFrame.Title.Text = "Perks"
local function onButtonAClick()
    unitFrame.Title.Text = "perks"
end

local function sprintButton() 
    if sprinting == false then
        sprinting = true
        player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 20
        unitFrame.buttonA.Text = "strinting"
    end
    if sprinting == true then
        sprinting = false
        player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
        unitFrame.buttonA.Text = "walking"
    end
end

buttona.MouseButton1Click:connect(sprintButton)
```

what i am trying to do is make a sprinting toggle program. The only problem is that it will work once then not work at all. i can click it and it changes the text then when i click it again it does nothing. i want it to be able to work every time you press it.

Comment: Do connected handlers fire once and then need to be re-connected? Do they need to return `true` or `false` or something to stay connected? Does changing the text of a button disconnect handlers?

Comment: ummmm i don't think so.

Comment: based off of this code on the roblox wiki you can toggle it so i don't know what is happening  `local button = script.Parent
local sound = button:WaitForChild('Sound')
 
sound:Play()
 
local function onButtonClick()
 if sound.IsPlaying then
  button.Image = 'rbxgameasset://Images/MusicOff'
  sound:Stop()
 else
  button.Image = 'rbxgameasset://Images/MusicOn'
  sound:Play()
 end
end
 
button.MouseButton1Click:connect(onButtonClick)`

Comment: I'm confused, you haven't responded to my answer, did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function you test 2 if statements. If sprinting is false, and if it it is true.

The key to understanding your problem is that your if statements counteract eachother.

Let's walk through this, first it detects if it's false. No, sprinting is not false. Then if checks if it's true. It is! So it sets it to false.

Great so far, right? Well here's your problem. When you try it again, sprinting is false. So the first if statement is run, and it sets it to true. But then, ANOTHER if statement is run immediately after. Since it's now true, this runs, setting it to false. It appears nothing happened.

Your solution? Take out the end to the first if statement, and replace the second if to an elseif. This way once one statement evaluated to true, it won't evaluate the next.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is not correct. As warspyking said, you have an issue with your conditionals. Fix this by adding an `elseif` statement instead.

```
local function sprintButton() 
    if not sprinting then
        sprinting = true
        player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 20
        unitFrame.buttonA.Text = "sprinting"
    elseif sprinting then
        sprinting = false
        player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
        unitFrame.buttonA.Text = "walking"
    end
end
```

Comment: Not to come off as offensive, but what was the point in this answer? You restated exactly what I said, with little explaination as to why this is.

Comment: @warspyking not to come out as obvious, but OP perhaps would've liked a VISUAL example. This is StackOverflow, where everybody contributes where they feel others lacked.

Comment: Point taken, but now he has 2 examples with an explaination, and example. Which should he accept?

Comment: @warspyking Usually, on StackOverflow, OP will accept your answer but upvote mine.

Comment: That might never even happen he appears to have disappeared.

Comment: @warspyking It is our duty to retrieve him back. I fear that he may have known something important; and thus, he has been captured. We must plan a rescue! It seems like suicide... but it is our duty as programmers to save him!

Comment: Hmmm... You may be right. I bet he found the secret to AI Intelligience that's more capable than the human brain... But wait, why would he be here with a simple elseif problem (???)